# Tab background color remaining unchanged

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, toolbar, transparent

I've been following some examples explained in this github: https://github.com/yannbf/ionic3-components/blob/master

And in one of those examples they present a page with a almost transparent toolbar
with this piece of code:

```
page-real-estate-listing {
 $black-overlay: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 $text-color: #666;
 $banner-text-color: white;
 $content-color: whitesmoke;
 $detail-background: rgba(236,236,236,.8);

/* Header */
.toolbar-background {
    border-color: transparent;
    background: $black-overlay;
} 
....
}
```

When I tried to apply this code it wouldn't work, after observing the elements I found that, his element was something like this:

```
<div class="toolbar-background toolbar-background-md"></div>
```

While mine looked like this:

```
<div class="toolbar-background toolbar-background-md" ng-reflect-klass="toolbar-background" ng-reflect-ng-class="toolbar-background-md"></div>
```

Angular seems to be injecting some classes into the toolbar. Is this causing the erratic behaviour [image]

I believe we're using different versions of ionic. Are these new angular classes interfering with my custom toolbar styles ? How can I stop this ? I'm really new to ionic, so I'm sorry if this question comes off as idiotic. Thanks

Edit: How it should behave [image]

Comment: where you are trying to make toolbar transparent ? in detail page or every where in your app ?

Comment: Only in my detail page

Answer (score 0):

I think for your detail page you need to do below code in your CSS file :

```
.detailpage {
  ion-header::after {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none !important;
  }
  .toolbar {
    .toolbar-background{
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will helps!